# "has no method 'property'" is being thrown on functions

Tags: ember.js

I have the following object I am creating:

```
Ember.Object.create({
  value: function() {
    return 'text';
  }.property()
});
```

But I am getting `has no method 'property'` errors. Not sure why, I thought `property` was available for all functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you open your JavaScript console you'll notice the following error:

**Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Ember.Object.create no longer supports defining computed properties.**

Try this instead:

```
App.Object = Ember.Object.extend({
  value: function() {
    return 'text';
  }.property()
});

alert(App.Object.create().get('value'));
```

In Ember, you should be creating objects, not instances. If you find yourself creating instances of objects like this, then you're *probably* doing something wrong. There are of course cases where you'll need to create `Ember.Object`s straight away, but for them to have computed properties, and to call `_super`? I can't think of any valid cases for that, and since they've since been **@deprecated**, you'll have to find alternative solutions. Better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had prototype extensions disabled:

http://emberjs.com/guides/configuring-ember/disabling-prototype-extensions/

Comment: That was my first answer, but I tried it out and realised that they removed the ability to create computed properties with `create`. Maybe you're using an older version of Ember, because the aforementioned is definitely true with the latest Ember.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use docs examples for Model: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ComputedProperty.html#method_property